# freestyle on workbench engin in blender 2.8

Tags: edges, freestyle, workbench-render-engine

in blender 2.8 ,is there is any way to make real time **freestyle** on **workbench engin** or (real time edges outline) --- like CAD software (no lighting setup just focus on modeling design with clear sharp edges.
[image]